# Unable to bind event with link button on a user control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, controls

There are two user controls, which are built dynamically.

In the first control, I am adding a link button, and trying to attach a click event on the same. But the event is not fired.

Actually the main goal is, when the link is clicked, based on which one is clicked, I need to show second control (the values on the new controls are based on the first controls link button that is clicked).

If I use javascript, I will need to use ActiveX or is there any other way to instantiate the second control using javascript

Any other ideas to achieve the scenario "main goal" are welcome

Edit: the linkbutton is not linked to the event at the postback. Can you guys suggest any idea to load another control in any other way?

Comment: does the second control have any values required from the server, does it require an event to be handled. What is the second control.  Using JQuery could you not attach an event to the onclick method of the first control to show the second control....???

Comment: Yes, the second control requires the values based on the first controls link that is clicked. Both are user controls. I have not tried JQuery, may be can you provide some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the link button is recreated on PostBack, before events are handled.  Be weary of where the button is added and when. Also if a control collection is altered (e.g. for example a control is deleted,  its id may  change and the event handler wont be invoked.!!